# Gnome Low/Critical Battery Notification

Tags: debian, gnome, battery

Base System: Debian 9 64-bit | Gnome 3.22.2

By default I get low and critical battery notification banners that remain in the notification tray until I click on them. However neither of these (or any other notification) will show above applications in full screen. How do I get them to?

I have found many scripts that will do this for me but since there seems to be something generating these notifications already I would rather just add the behaviour I want to the existing notifications.

I have also looked through the Gnome Notification Standard and am aware that it is possible to set notifications as critical or urgent but I cannot find the component that is generating these notifications.

I do not have gnome-power-manager installed, the distribution came with UPower installed and I have looked through the upower.conf file and can adjust the percentage or time when the notifications are generated but not the notifications themselves.